# Keep failing to generating a table in Rmarkdown beamer with the following error message

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, beamer

I am trying to create the following table (attached below) within rmarkdown beamer (Rstudio). It initially worked but since I updated R (3.6.3) and Rstudio, it hasn't worked. I also updated all the pkgs and reinstalled tinytex pkg, but it keeps generating the following error message:

```
output file: dp02_slide.knit.md

! File ended while scanning use of \beamer@collect@@body.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> dp02_slide.tex

Error: LaTeX failed to compile dp02_slide.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See dp02_slide.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

```
---
title: "Big Business" 
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
      citation_package: natbib
      theme: "boxes"
header-includes:
- \widowpenalties 1 150
- \usepackage{amsmath}
- \renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
- \usepackage{adjustbox}
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{tikz}
- \usepackage{verbatim}
- \usepackage{chronosys}
- \usepackage{stackengine}
- \usepackage{xcolor}
- \usepackage{babel}
- \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
- \usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}
- \usetikzlibrary{intersections}
- \usepackage[font=small]{caption}
- \usepackage{adjustbox}
- \usepackage{tabularx}
- \usepackage{pgfplots}
- \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
- \usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
- \renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
- \usepackage{subcaption}
- \usepackage{wrapfig}
---
# Table 1
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\small
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\columnwidth,center}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\hline\hline
Stages & \textit{Financial regimes} & \textit{Preferential target} & \textit{Loan interest rates} & \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}c@{}}\textit{Inequality} \\ \textit{trends} \\ \textit{(prediction)} \end{tabular} \\ [0.5ex]\hline
Stage I (1960s) &  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}c@{}}Repressed\\(Industry-neutral) \end{tabular} & Exporting firms & \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}c@{}}Preferential rate ($r^{I}$)\\(based on \\export performance) \end{tabular}&$\searrow$?\\[1ex]\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: Can you please make a [mre] that we can copy+paste to reproduce your problem?

Comment: If I use your code fragment in a basic test document, it compiles fine.

Comment: I replaced it by the shorter code of same issue. I hope it works. I also attached the table that I want to generate as a link. Thanks @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Comment: Unfortunately you still only show a code fragment instead of a small test document that would allow us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think this is something you expect. Otherwise, please let me know. Thanks for your patience @samcarter

Answer (score 0):

Rmarkdown seems to be incapable to deal with optional arguments in square brackets. As a workaround you could have the whole table as true latex code.

Some other remarks about your code:

- You don't need `\usepackage{amsmath}` and `\usepackage{xcolor}`. Beamer already loads them
- The `babel` package needs to know which language you want
- packages like `caption` are usually also not necessary because beamer has its own mechanism for captions etc.
- it does not make sense to use floating specifier like `[h!]` in a doumentclass that has no floating mechanism
- you don't need `\centering` in the table. beamer centres tables and figures automatically
- I would recommend to not scale elements which contain text. Instead of `\begin{adjustbox}{width=\columnwidth,center}...\end{adjustbox}` it would be much better to choose a suitable font size to make sure that the letters used will have the best shape for the size they are shown in.

---

````
---
title: "Big Business" 
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
      citation_package: natbib
      theme: "boxes"
header-includes:
- \widowpenalties 1 150
- \usepackage{amsmath}
- \renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
- \usepackage{adjustbox}
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{tikz}
- \usepackage{verbatim}
- \usepackage{chronosys}
- \usepackage{stackengine}
- \usepackage{xcolor}
- \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
- \usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}
- \usetikzlibrary{intersections}
- \usepackage[font=small]{caption}
- \usepackage{adjustbox}
- \usepackage{tabularx}
- \usepackage{pgfplots}
- \renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
- \usepackage{subcaption}
- \usepackage{wrapfig}
---
# Table 1
```{=latex}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\small
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\columnwidth,center}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\hline\hline
Stages & \textit{Financial regimes} & \textit{Preferential target} & \textit{Loan interest rates} & \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}c@{}}\textit{Inequality} \\ \textit{trends} \\ \textit{(prediction)} \end{tabular} \\ [0.5ex]\hline
Stage I (1960s) &  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}c@{}}Repressed\\(Industry-neutral) \end{tabular} & Exporting firms & \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}c@{}}Preferential rate ($r^{I}$)\\(based on \\export performance) \end{tabular}&$\searrow$?\\[1ex]\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```
````

https://rstudio.cloud/project/1203195

Comment: This code seems to work in the environment that you kindly link, but my rmarkdown still generates the same error msg: am I missing something here? (I revised code as you suggest).     
! File ended while scanning use of \beamer@collect@@body.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> dp02_slide.tex

Error: LaTeX failed to compile dp02_slide.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See dp02_slide.log for more info.
Execution halted

Comment: @joe Can you add `keep_tex: true` and show the resulting .tex file?

Comment: I just added tex file upon your request. In fact, it generates the following error msg this time:  File ended while scanning use of \beamer@collect@@body.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> slide01.tex

Error: LaTeX failed to compile slide01.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See slide01.log for more info.
Execution halted

Comment: @joe mmm, somehow your rmarkdown fails to recognise the \`\`\`{=latex} block...

Comment: it works perfect when I remove the following codes that enables multiple lines within the cell:  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}c@{}}Repressed\\(Industry-neutral) \end{tabular}. Maybe I should look for alternative way to do the job?

Comment: @joe That's a really complicate way for writing multiline cells anyway. I would suggest to look into columns of fixed with, e.g. with `p{0.2\textwidth}` instead of `c` or have a look into the tabularx package which you are loading anyway

Comment: Finally I could resolve the issue by using `\makecell{}`. Like you said, I used such a complicated way to have multiple lines.  Appreciate all your comments and helps!